# How do I list all existing open vpn certificates

Tags: linux, certificate, users, clients

I need to know how to view existing certificates in OpenVPN, the internal documentation passed me (written by a past employer) contains creating, removing, retrieving and revoking user, see below

/etc/openvpn/getclient.sh

/etc/openvpn/revokeclient.sh

rm /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/3.0.6/pki/private/.key

rm /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/3.0.6/pki/reqs/.req

rm /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/3.0.6/pki/issued/.crt

A record of existing certificates has never been maintained so suspect that is a large number that can now be deleted.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You can't know.

A certificate is *signed* by the Certificate Authority (CA), but it should *not* be stored by anyone but the owner of the certificate. Furthermore, the CA need not even be yours; you can trust external CA's if you want.

Certificate issuance is totally offline and there is no central repository of certificates - the security stems from the fact that it's impossible to forge the signature, so there's no need for a central repository - which also gives flexibility.

Furthermore, you cannot *delete* certificates. You can revoke them, marking them as invalid. But as they can be stored on other systems, there's no way you can delete them.

As you effectively have no idea of what's been issued and not, I would start over at this point, reissuing certificates. I would suggest that you use some sort of directory, such as FreeIPA or Active Directory to keep track of and automatically issue and rotate certificates.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -ltr /etc/openvpn/clients/
```

For client certificates

You can also cat them all if you want to view the contents

```
cat /etc/openvpn/clients/*.crt
```

For the server certificates

```
cat /etc/openvpn/server.crt
```

Or using openssl

For client certificates

```
openssl x509 -in /etc/openvpn/clients/*.crt -text
```

For the server certificates

```
openssl x509 -in /etc/openvpn/server.crt -text
```

Comment: There's no reason why the server would keep any client certs around. There's no reason why the server would have any client configuration at all.

Comment: @vidarlo There is no reason, but EasyRSA usually keeps them and usually it is used with OpenVPN (and, it seems to be used, according to the question). It then uses it when revocation is requested — to resolve the serial of the certificate to be revoked from the CN.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov True - but you can't really be certain of either that or that the key material has not been copied. I would *not* trust such an setup, as any outgoing admin could simply copy the private key and issue their own certs...